# Select all descendant HTML elements with a certain class that don't have an element with an other specific class in between

Tags: jquery, css

Assume you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="root-component" class="script-component">a0
            <div></div>
            <div class="component">a2</div>
            <div class="script-component">b
                <div class="component">b1
                    <div class="script-component">c
                    </div>
                    <div class="component">b2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="component">a3</div>
            <div class="component">a4</div>
            <div>            
                <div class="component">a5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="component"> a6            
                <div class="component">a7</div>
            </div>
            <div class="component">a8
                <div class="script-component"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

From the `root-component` I would like to select all child elements with a `component` class until and not including the elements with the `script-component` class. 
This means at the end only the elements with an `a` text (a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7 and a8 should be selected) should be selected.

Edit: Or in Trung's words: The goal is to skip searching for components down the tree once script-component class is encountered.

Edit2: Or in even other words: I would like to select all `.component` children until a `.script-component` is encountered.

It can be done using jQuery and CSS.

You can use this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pgegsjja/ to try it out.

Comment: So what you're trying to say is to skip searching down the tree once script-component class is encountered?

Comment: Yes, thats right. I will add that to the question.

Comment: I also tried combinations of `.find()` and `.parentsUntil()` but with no success so far.

Comment: Not totally sure what solution you want. Do you want to only show divs with the `.script-component` class if there is text in the div or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: It is more complicated than that. I would like to select all `.component` children until a `.script-component` is encountered.

Comment: This selects all `.component` within a `.component`. What other rules are there? http://jsfiddle.net/pgegsjja/1/

Comment: Which text should be selected in your fiddle?

Comment: According to my description "This means at the end only the elements with the `a` text should be selected." Sadly your solution doesn't do that yet jonmrich.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89401/discussion-between-sandro-and-jonmrich).

Comment: Did you already think on recursive method? 
something like function recursive(element){
 $(element).each(function(){
 if($(this).class('.component')){ alert($(this).html());
         for(int i =0; i<$(this).children().length;i++)
               recursive($(this));
}
else{break;}
});
}

Comment: Yeah, I thought about something like this if there is no appropriate selector.

Comment: The main `root-component` also has class of `script-component` so breaks logic selecting `component` class where it is not a descendant of `script-component`

Comment: Sadly it's the same in real life.

Comment: Since `a8` has a `script-component` it shouldn't be selected as well, right?

Comment: `a8` should be selected. But not the `.script-component` below.

Answer (score 1):

This selects all the `a` components. Test it out and see if it suits your requirements.

`$('#root-component').find(".component").siblings(':not(.script-component)').css("color", "red");`

Comment: It's a good point. But as you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/pgegsjja/3/ it doesn't really stop at the `.script-component` as the `b3` element I added below is also selected.

Answer (score 1):

Filter function tests against less than 2 matches because we need to include class `script-component` occurring in the `root-component` div.

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].parents = function (a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).parents(m[3]).length < 2;
};

// The b2 element is still selected so it is not yet correct
$('#root-component').find(':not(.script-component) .component, >.component').css("color", "red");

$('.component').filter(':parents(.script-component)').css("color", "blue");
```

```css
div {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root-component" class="script-component">a0
    <div></div>
    <div class="component">a2</div>
    <div class="script-component">b
        <div class="component">b1
            <div class="script-component">c</div>
            <div class="component">b2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="component">a3</div>
    <div class="component">a4</div>
    <div>
        <div class="component">a5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="component">a6
        <div class="component">a7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="component">a8
        <div class="script-component"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Trung! It does select the right elements but I'm not 100% sure if I can use it in my real case (not the stripped down example here) as I don't understand what's actually happening and I don't find good documentation about that sizzle feature.

Comment: Filter removes certain matches from the first selector matches. The custom function then tests how many times our excluded selector is found in all parents up the tree. `.length` is how many times the filtered selector was found. In this example case it will always be 1 occurence due to root-component having the same class we are filtering against so we need to allow for at least 1 occurence (i.e. less than 2 occurences)

Comment: 1 matched filtered occurrence would return 0 for length. If you didn't want to allow for the occurrence in the root-component at all, i.e. Do not include if any parent ancestor matches filter, then you could simple test against `= 0` or `< 1`

Comment: Hope you understand it now ;-)
Maybe if you could expand on your real case, then I might be able to help further

Comment: Thanks for the explaination! Do you have a link to the documentation of that feature? This way I can see what `a, i, m` really means and how the syntax of `expr[':'].parents` really works.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly: If I would like to be more descriptive I could write:
`$('.component').filter(':moreThanOneParentWith(.script-component)').css("color", "blue");`
if I define the pseudo like this: `jQuery.expr[':'].moreThanOneParentWith = function...`

Comment: I guess `a` is the currently selected element and `m[3]` represents `.script-component` for some reason. Is that right?

Comment: The disadvantage of course is, that it first selects all `.component` elements   (which could be a lot in the practical case) and after that filters the wrong one. But if there is no other solution within some days I would accept that as the right answer if I understand more of the background and I'm sure what it is actually doing.

Comment: The API of the sizzle pseudo selectors can be found [here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#user-content--pseudo-selectors-pseudos) but it does not yet explain what the parameters actually mean and it doesn't contain a description of what the method does.

Comment: I think the sizzle pseudo function has an equal result to passing a function to jQuerys filter method like documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function). As jQuerys function argument is better documented I will go for that one but I will still mark this answer as solution if there is no one that matches the exact result on the first run in the next days.